# Java Web Start from Command Line in Silent Mode

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am trying to execute Java Web Start in silent mode using `-silent -Xnosplash`. My arguments look like `-silent -Xnosplash -J-Detl.schdeuler = ""`.....

The splash screen doesn't appear after using `-Xnosplash`, however `-silent` that apparently hide the downloading progress still appears. Could anyone help me with this ? I have an environment that only has command line available with no GUI due to security concerns and therefore I need to hide these popups.

Answer (score 0):

According to the the [`javaws`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html) [`man`](http://manned.org/javaws/8082dda8) page, the `-silent` option is meant to be used with the `-import` option:

> When used with the `-import` option, imports in silent mode; i.e., there  will be  no  UI pop up. The process exit code will be either 0 if successful or 1 if not.

Comment: this option i tired but it dosen't work . it still shows the UI pop up

Comment: Unless you have previously accepted the certificate, you'll get the security challenge.